# loweredrolename in aspnet_users table (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, role, aspnetdb

For my existing data, both RoleName and LoweredRoleName are same, but some are lower case and some are in same case too.

Anyone knows what is the use of column LoweredRoleName in aspnet_users table?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. I think used internally by .net. Maybe LoweredRoleName is used to avoid using SQL's `LOWER()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a reason for it, on the cusp it seems redundant and a design smell.